# open menu the user right-clicks on specific words? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to open custom context menu to open when the user right-clicks on specific words? JavaScript

I've been looking for that for a long time how can I For a word that has textarea the custom context menu opened the word should be specific have in the array to recognize him Can anyone help me. That's just an example of a context menu, not in a textarea like this https://codepen.io/rebaz-xoshnaw-the-builder/pen/XWOPvRe if textarea value not have specificwords word It shouldn't be open The code I put as a suggestion for my request has nothing to do with the source

var specificwords = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'hey', 'some', 'howdy'];

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var startPosition = this.selectionStart,
            endPosition = this.selectionEnd;

        while (this.value.charAt(startPosition) !== ' ' && startPosition >= 0) {
            startPosition--;
        }

        while (this.value.charAt(endPosition) !== ' ' && endPosition < this.value.length) {
            endPosition++;
        }

        this.selectionStart = startPosition + 1;
        this.selectionEnd = endPosition;
})
```

```html
   <textarea>hello This is some text. Click on any word and then do right click</textarea>
```

```
   document.getElementById("my-message").addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
      // Prevent the usual context menu from appearing
      e.preventDefault();
      
      // Show our custom context menu instead
      window.todesktop.contextMenu.create([
        {
          label: "Add Emoji",
          click: () => {
            // In this case, you would provide the `showEmojiPanel` function
            showEmojiPanel();
          },
        },
        { type: "separator" },
        { role: "copy" },
        { role: "paste" },
      ]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before opening up your custom context menu, get the string value of the textarea. Simply split the string value of the text area, find all the words it contains and check if the specific words you are looking for
are included.

If the array of the words of the string value from the textarea contains any specific word, open your custom context menu. If not, do not trigger any event.

```js
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
let contextMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-context-menu")[0];
specificwords = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'hey', 'some', 'howdy'];

textarea.oncontextmenu = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let string = event.target.value;
    let words = string.split(' ');
    let result = words.filter(word => specificwords.includes(word))

    if (result.length > 0) {
        let x = event.pageX, y = event.pageY;
        contextMenu.style.left = x + "px";
        contextMenu.style.top = y + "px";
        contextMenu.style.display = "block";

        contextMenu.classList.add("on");
    }
}

document.onclick = (event) => {
    if (contextMenu.classList.contains("on")) {
        contextMenu.classList.remove("on");
        contextMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.custom-context-menu {
    z-index: 1100;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
}

.custom-context-menu li {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-context-menu li:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>hello This is some text. Click on any word and then do right click</textarea>
    <ul class="custom-context-menu">
        <li>rule</li>
        <li>slde</li>
        <li>rebaz</li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </html>
```

Comment: thanks... but can help me how run your source code.